# How do you fill fields on a form using a selectedindexchanged event?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, combobox

I fill my combobox in the page load event as displayed below.

```
try
        {
            List<PreviousVersionData> listID = PreviousVersionData.getDatabase();
            if (listID != null)
            {
                foreach (PreviousVersionData l in listID)
                {
                    cmboBoxPreviousVersion.Items.Add(l.FormatID.ToString() + " - " + l.FormatName);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

That part runs perfectly but I want to access the database to get the rest of the corresponding fields so they can be edited. I figured you could right a method to get the data based of the selectedvalue. The selected value returns null for every value. I have provided my code for the field fill event also. Any ideas on why I am getting a null value and how to correct this. Also feel free to ask for clarification or more info on something.

```
if (cmboBoxPreviousVersion.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            PreviousVersionData pvdata = new PreviousVersionData();
            pvdata = pvdata.getDataByID(cmboBoxPreviousVersion.SelectedValue.ToString());

            Item.FormatID = pvdata.FormatID;
            Item.FormatName = pvdata.FormatName;
            Item.FormatDescription = pvdata.FormatDescription;
            Item.StockID = pvdata.StockID;
            Item.PrintPlantCode = (bool)pvdata.PrintPlantCode;
            Item.PrintWeight = (bool)pvdata.PrintWeight;
            Item.PrintPrice = (bool)pvdata.PrintPrice;

            rChkBoxPlantCode.Checked = Item.PrintPlantCode;
            rChkBoxPrintPrice.Checked = Item.PrintPrice;
            rChkBoxWeight.Checked = Item.PrintWeight;
            cmboBoxStock.Items.Add(Item.StockID);
            rTxtBoxDescription.Text = Item.FormatDescription;
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
cmboBoxPreviousVersion.SelectedItem
```

**OR** you could also use:

```
cmboBoxPreviousVersion.SelectedIndex
```

to return the index of the item.